# Is it possible to get sql column metadata from pandas DataFrame in python?

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, metadata

I read some database table with python to a pandas DataFrame and I am able to retrieve the type of the columns:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas
with sqlite3.connect('d:\database.sqlite') as connection:
    dataFrame = pandas.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM my_table', connection)

dataFrame.dtypes
```

[image]

I am wondering if the DataFrame also includes further metadata about the table, e.g. if a column is nullable, the default value of the column and if the column is a primary key?

I would expect some methods like

```
dataFrame.isNullable('columnName')
```

but could not find such methods.

If the meta data is not included in the DataFrame I would have to use an extra query to retrieve that data, e.g.

```
PRAGMA table_info('my_table')
```

That would give the columns

```
cid, name, type, notnull, dflt_value, pk
```

However, I would like to avoid that extra query. Especially if my original query does not contain all columns or if it defines some extra columns it could become complicated to find the corresponding metadata.

=>If the DataFrame already contains the wanted metadata, please let me know how to access it.

(In Java I would access the metadata with `ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();` )

Comment: Since the purpose of pandas is to simplify and perform bulk changes to data set from number of data sources, it basically provides extension for data analytics and data science operations. 
As for your case, you can fetch your meta data from sqlite from "select * from sqlite_master".